# How to pass node queue id in views contextual filters

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I a list of node queues and nodes associated with them. Now I have created a block using views. This block should list the nodes in a specific node queue based on the node queue id.

I have used node id in contextual filters, but not sure how to use node queue's id in contextual filter.

Any help would be widely appreciated.

Comment: are you using nodequeue module?

Comment: Yes I am using node queue module.

Comment: Did you try this module before https://drupal.org/project/nodequeue_extras ?

Comment: No, but will try now and will get back to you. Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give a try to [nodequeue_extras](https://drupal.org/project/nodequeue_extras) module

> Provides 2 pieces of helper functionality specific to Nodequeue and Views:
>
> 1. Contextual nodequeue edit links for views that include a nodequeue relationship.
> 2. A special Views nodequeue relationship and subqueue argument that let you build views based on a subqueue without requiring that all result nodes in the view exist in the subqueue.

Comment: Arpitr, you nodequeue extras was the perfect solution here. Please do add that as a answer, so that I can accept that :)